# ImageButton background color shifts the button up?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set the background colour of an ImageButton to black, but it shifts the whole image up for some reason. That is, without the background colour, it looks like:

[image]

With the background color set, it looks like:

[image]

Here's what my layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp">


<FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_button"
            />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textColor="@color/secondary_string"
              android:textSize="10dp"
              android:text="5"/>
</FrameLayout>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It only seems to be the case if the ImageButton is wrapped in the FrameLayout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, background is default `drawable` resource so it has some basic rules (default size).

You should specify your button height manually like:

```
  <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_button"
            />
```

or set height to match parent like:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: Right. Does that mean padding will need to be manually specified if background is used?

Comment: You should specify width and/or height manually instead. Updated my answer.